# Prove for every $1 \leq n$, that $47\mid3^n4^{2n}-1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I tried to solve with induction, base $n=1$ is correct such that, $\frac{3*16-1}{47}=1$.

Then assuming that for $n$ the statement is correct such that,  $3^n4^{2n} \equiv 0 \pmod {47}$.

We need prove that for $n+1$ is true such that, $\frac{(3*16*48^n)-1}{47}$ .

Then I tried to simplify it to $\frac{48}{47}*48^n-\frac{1}{47}= 1\frac{1}{47}*48^n-\frac{1}{47}=\frac{(3^n4^{2n})+47(3^n4^{2n})}{47}-\frac{1}{47}=\frac{(3^n4^{2n})}{47}-\frac{1}{47}+3^n4^{2n}$

We get that from $\frac{(3^n4^{2n})}{47}-\frac{1}{47}+3^n4^{2n}$, the expression  $\frac{(3^n4^{2n})} {47}-\frac{1}{47}$ is from the assumption so we are left with $3^n4^{2n}$ which is a natural number.

Is that proof enough to show that $47\mid3^n4^{2n}-1$?

Comment: $47$ is a prime, which does not divide $3^n4^{2n}$.

Comment: And certainly not for $n<1$.

Comment: Did you mean to prove that $47\mid 3^n4^{2n} - 1$?

Comment: This is impossible: $47$ is prime, and the prime factors of the r.h.s. are $2$ and $3$.

Comment: @Théophile typo, i mean $1 \leq n$

Comment: @octave yes, i forgot to add the minus 1

Comment: @Bernard edited title

Comment: Hint: $3^n4^{2n}-1 = 48^n-1=(47+1)^n-1$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
No induction required. For a direct proof, use congruences $\bmod 47$ and observe that : $$3^n4^{2n}-1=(3\cdot 4^2)^n-1. $$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :** $3 \cdot 4^2 = 48 \equiv 1 \pmod{47}$

Answer (score 1):

Transform ($3^n4^{2n}-1) \to$ ($3^n16^n-1) \to (48^n-1)$

For sum of geometric series

$1+x+x^2+x^3+...+x^{n-1}=\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$

or

$x^n-1=(x-1)(1+x+x^2+x^3+...+x^{n-1})$

Set x=48,

$48^n-1=(48-1)(1+48+48^2+48^3+...+48^{n-1})$

=
$47 (1+48+48^2+48^3+...+48^{n-1}) \to  47\mid3^n4^{2n}-1$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $3^n\cdot 4^{2n}=48^n$, by using the binomial theorem you have $$(47+1)^n-1=\sum_{i=1}^{47}\binom{47}{i}47^i$$

And so every term is divisible by $47$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $3^n4^{2n}-1 = 48^n-1$.
Using induction:

$n=1: 48^1-1=47$ is divisible by $47$ and

$48^{n+1}-1 = 48(48^n-1)+47$ and $48^n-1$ is divisible by $47$ per induction hypothesis.